# What is the fromage option in the Indeed XML Job Search API?

Tags: json, xml, html

Here's the link to the API: https://ads.indeed.com/jobroll/xmlfeed

You might need to login to see it, but here's the raw text. fromage is one of the options and I'm trying to figure out what it does precisely, to no avail:

> **st**    Site type. To show only jobs from job boards use "jobsite". For jobs from direct employer websites use "employer".
>
> **jt**    Job type. Allowed values: "fulltime", "parttime", "contract", "internship", "temporary".
>
> **start** Start results at this result number, beginning with 0. Default is 0.
>
> **limit** Maximum number of results returned per query. Default is 10
>
> **fromage**   Number of days back to search.
>
> **highlight** Setting this value to 1 will bold terms in the snippet that are also present in q. Default is 0.
>
> **filter**    Filter duplicate results. 0 turns off duplicate job filtering. Default is 1.
>
> **latlong**   If latlong=1, returns latitude and longitude information for each job result. Default is 0.
>
> **co**    Search within country specified. Default is us See below for a complete list of supported countries.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out by just tweaking in query in the url. It acts as the "days ago posted". For example, if you need to get jobs that were posted in the last 24 hours, you use `1`. If you need it within this week, you use `7`. It's useful to keep the query fresh and up to date.